# jquery toggle css of div position

Tags: jquery, html, css, position, toggle

Can someone please please help me!!!
So I want to make `.button` a button to move the `#about_me` `div` to `0vh` but I don't really understand jquery, what am I doing wrong here haha, please explain as if to an infant :)

the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button").click(function(){
    $("div.about_me").toggleClass(".about_me_active");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="background"><h1>Indiana Porter</h1><h2>Digital Artist</h2>

<div class="button">About Me</div>

<div class="about_me"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: Arvo;
    color:white;
    font-size:1.5vw;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Arvo;
    src: url(Arvo-Regular.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Arvo-bold;
    src: url(Arvo-Bold.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Arvo-italic;
    src: url(Arvo-Italic.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Arvo-bold-italic;
    src: url(Arvo-BoldItalic.ttf);
}
#background{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    max-width:100%;
    background:url("background.jpg");
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
    background-origin:center;
    background-size:cover;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#background h1{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    top:15vh;
    font-family:Arvo-bold;
    font-size:8vw;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:0 0 2vw rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
#background h2{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    top:15vh;
    font-family:Arvo-bold;
    font-size:3vw;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:0 0 2vw rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.button{
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    font-size:1.5vw;
    position:absolute;
    width:8vw;
    left:45vw;
    top:80vh;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    border-radius:.4vw;
    padding:1vh 1vw;
    cursor:pointer;
    box-shadow:0 0 2vw black;
    transition:.5s;
}
.button:hover{
    box-shadow:0 0 2vw white;
}
.about_me{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    max-width:100%;
    background:url("about_me.jpg");
    position:absolute;
    top:100vh;
}
.about_me_active{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    max-width:100%;
    background:url("about_me.jpg");
    position:absolute;
    top:0vh;
}
```

Comment: `toggleClass(".about_me_active")` remove `.` should be `toggleClass("about_me_active")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toggle class doesn't need the period before the class  name

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button").click(function(){
    $(".about_me").toggleClass("about_me_active");
  });
});
```

```css
.about_me{
   width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    max-width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    top:100vh;
}
.about_me_active{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    max-width:100%;
    background-color:black;
    position:absolute;
    top:0vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="background"><h1>Indiana Porter</h1><h2>Digital Artist</h2>

<div class="button">About Me</div>

<div class="about_me"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the "." on `toggleClass`

Here's a cleaner way to go about it...

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button").click(function(){
    $("div.about_me").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.about_me{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    max-width:100%;
    background:url("about_me.jpg");
    position:absolute;
    top:100vh;
}
.active{
    top:0vh;
}
```

You don't need the extra CSS on the active state.